# Is it OK to say "I drink much water"?

Tags: uncountable-nouns

There was a question like this:

> **Which alternatives are correct? Sometimes only one alternative is correct, and sometimes two alternatives are possible.**
>
> 10. I drink ___ water every day.
>
> **A** much
>
> **B** a lot of
>
> **C** lots of

I've already known B and C and those were on my key answer. However, I don't know why A was incorrect. Can you tell me why? Because I'm sure we usually use **much** with uncountable nouns and water itself is uncountable. For example: much luck, much time, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just isn't the usual expression in that use. It's not ungrammatical, but saying it that way would identify the speaker as an English language learner.

On the other hand, in a question or in some statements, it's ordinary:

Do you drink much water?
How much water do you drink?

If you drink much tea, you may get nervous.